# Is NSURL supposed to parse invalid URLs?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

I could not really find this in the documentation.

I'm writing some unit tests and one of the tests that is supposed to fail is `[NSURL URLWithString: @"cow"]`. Because `cow` is not a valid URL.

However, it is happily parsed by `NSURL` with no errors at all. It does not return `nil` and it does not throw an exception. Calling `[url absoluteString]` on it turns it back into `@"cow"`.

What is going on here? Is `NSURL` really supposed to allow this?

Comment: As @Chuck points out, @"cow" is a valid URL. Something like @"cow bell" shouldn't be, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSURL allows relative URLs, which would include "cow".

The general form of a URI given in RFC 2396 allows relative references:

```
URI-reference = [ absoluteURI | relativeURI ] [ "#" fragment ]
relativeURI   = ( net_path | abs_path | rel_path ) [ "?" query ]
rel_path      = rel_segment [ abs_path ]
rel_segment   = 1*( unreserved | escaped |
                      ";" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | "," )
```

Unless I'm misreading horribly, this means any sequence of valid characters can form a valid relative URL.

Comment: Yes, but not through `+URLWithString:`.

Comment: The documentation says the URL is parsed according to RFC 1808 — a document titled "Relative Uniform Resource Locators," which allows relative or absolute URLs. See page 3 of that RFC, or pages 14-16 of 2396 for the the same definition. Relative URLs are allowed.

Comment: Withdrawing my previous comment, replacing it with this: An obvious example I overlooked is href="/someotherdocument" used from within an existing hypertext document. I suppose it's up to the developer to maintain the context if relative URLs are given.

Comment: @Joshua Nozzi: Yep, the RFC actually says both that and what was in your deleted comment — "It must be emphasized that relative URI cannot be used reliably in situations where the document's base URI is not well-defined."

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for +URLWithString:

> The string with which to initialize
>   the NSURL object. Must conform to RFC
>   2396. This method parses URLString according to RFCs 1738 and 1808.
>   ... 
>   If the string was malformed, returns nil.

Not being intimately familiar with RFC 2396, I can't say for certain, but I think you must have a minimum of a protocol and a host (even if the domain itself forwards to a host). I'd certainly expect nil.

If you're not getting "nil" back by passing @"cow", you should file a bug at bugreporter.apple.com. You may want to title it, "Don't Have a Cow."

Comment: Correct. The base rule is specified in “3. URI Syntactic Components” as `<scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>`. “c:w” would match that, “cow” does not.

Comment: As I noted in a comment on my answer, Ahruman is mistaken in taking this as the mandatory form a URL must take to be parsed. Relative URLs are valid and allowed.